# Django - Alternatives To File Browser that Work Well With S3

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto, django-storage, django-filebrowser

[Django Filebrowser](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-filebrowser) does not work well with [storage services](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-filebrowser/issues/40#issue-ref-34723825).

[Django Filer](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-filer) found on [Django Packages](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/file-managers/) seems like a good alternative but its support of storage backends seems incomplete.

I would like to know what are other alternatives to Django's File Browser that integrate well with S3.

Answer (score 0):

I've used https://github.com/bradleyg/django-s3direct in my project. It worked nice. It is also listed on Django Packages site you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

When you include the `S3BotoStorageMixin`, this package should be able to work on S3.

```
from filebrowser.storage import S3BotoStorageMixin
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage


class CustomS3BotoStorage(S3BotoStorageMixin, S3BotoStorage):
    def path(self, name):
        # Workaround for django-filebrowser, which requests full_path on uploaded files.
        # The operation is not needed at all, since no chmod happens afterwards.
        return self.url(name)

    def isfile(self, name):
        # Hacky performance optimization for filebrowser.
        # The original isdir() method is really inefficient.
        if '.' in name:
            return True
        return super().isfile(name)
```

and in `settings.py`:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'myproject.lib.storages.CustomS3BotoStorage'
```

Comment: where and how should we add the mixin. Guidance would be much appreciated.